# Show that $S$ has elements of order $36$, $39$ but does not have an element of order $37$ or $38$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

This question was asked in my quiz and I  was unable to solve one part , so I am asking it here.

> Let S denote the group of all those permutations of the english alphabet that fix the letters $T,E,N,D,U,L,K,A,R$ .Other letters may or may not be fixed. Show that $S$ has elements of order $36 ,39$ but does not have an element of order $37$ or $38$.

> Attempt : Order of Group is $17!$. So , Group can have element of order $3$ and $13$ by Cauchy theorem (call $a$ and $b$ respectively) and so $ab$ will have order $39$. Also ,as order of element divides order of group so order $37$ or $38$ is not possible.

But I am not able to think about element of order $36$.

Kindly help with that !

Comment: Do you know about cycle decompositions of permutations?

Comment: The product of an element of order $3$ and another of order $13$ need not be $39$ - but it will be if they commute. $36 = 9\times 4$. To use the easy procedure for commuting elements you need coprime orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any $4$ letters which might not be fixed, call them $a_1,...,a_4$. Pick other $9$ letters which might not be fixed and are distinct from the $a_i$'s, call them $b_1,...,b_9$. Then the permutation $(a_1\ a_2\ a_3\ a_4)(b_1\ b_2\ ...\ b_9)$ has order lcm$(4,9)=36$.

By the way, it is in general not true that the order of $ab$ is the product of orders of $a$ and $b$, even if these orders are coprime. So in order to prove there is an element of order $39$ just repeat my argument for order $36$, just this time pick $3$ elements $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $13$ elements $b_1,...,b_{13}$.

Comment: First line of your answer :Take any 4 letters which "might" be fixed, call them a1,...,a4. Pick other 9 letters which "might not"  .is there a specific reason why you choose "might " in a's and might not in b's ? Also I think use of might will make the statement ambigouous . I am confused by what you mean by line 1

Comment: @Ben Sorry, it was a typo. Should be "might not" in both of them. Of course, if $a$ is a letter which must be fixed then you can't send it to something else. So we have to pick other letters, the ones that we might send to anything we want.